# Many to many relations MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create a database using MongoDB. Since I have no experience with NoSQL database I'm having some troubles with designing the database.

I want to make a database where one **student** can be part of multiple **sessions**, and one **session** can contain multiple **students** (many-to-many). Also, each **event** is linked to one **student** inside one **session**.

So far I designed it like this:

Sessions:

```
Sessions.students = [student_id1, student_id2]
```

Student:

```
Students.sessions = [session_id1, session_id2]
```

But my problem is, where should I store the relation, in sessions or in student, or in both (like above)?

And is this the correct way to create the event relationships?

Event:

```
Event.studentid = [student_id1]
Event.sessionid = [session_id1]
```

Comment: Is session a state you should be storing in the database? I'll assume session state changes frequently so you'll be modifying the session documents a lot..

Comment: Read https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1 for inspiration. There is no single "correct" way, but a number of "correct" ways with different efficiency in different queries. You need to estimate intended use of the data and design the schema that suits you best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you need to find how many students are in each session and how many sessions each student attends.

For Many-Many relations in mongodb store id's in each other collections.

2) if one of the questions is relevant for your project then only store ids accordingly.

ex: if you need to find session information not student information then store

session.student=[studentid1, id2 id3]; student.session=[] not required

Can also use indexing for searching but dont use too much of it.

Answer (score 2):

As a user you have 2 collections in the database called, students & sessions.

In students collection: each document contains an array of sessionIds & in sessions collection: each document contains array of studentIds.

To get data in list you need to use **aggregation**

- Query for students like

  ```
    students.aggregate({
      //here write query using $match, $unwind, $lookup
      //$unwind : sessionIds from sessions
    })
  ```
- Query for sessions like

  ```
    sessions({
      //here write query using $match, $unwind, $lookup
      //$unwind : studentIds from students
    })
  ```

Comment: No need to take array of `_id`... simple `_id` in each collection should be a good option...